# Android: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad conversation thread id: 15555215554

Tags: java, android, sms

I am trying to delete sms messages from android emulator and receiving next error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad conversation thread id: 15555215554
```

Does someone have the same problem and can help me to resolve this problem? 
The code for delete message next:

```
    try {
        final long thread_id = transactionCursor.getLong(1);
        Uri thread = Uri.parse("content://sms/conversations/" + thread_id);
        getContentResolver().delete(thread, null, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

in manifest file I have added next permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SMS" />
```

Comment: maybe the conversation id is really wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Ahmet, You are right and I understand it from the error message, simply changing from my code

```
try {
    final long thread_id = transactionCursor.getLong(transactionCursor.getColumnIndex("thread_id"));
    final Uri thread = Uri.parse("content://sms/conversations/" + thread_id);
    final int numberOfDeletedMessages = getContentResolver().delete(thread, null, null);
    Log.v(TAG, "Number of deleted messages equals to " + numberOfDeletedMessages);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG,e.getMessage(),e);
}
```

and all works successful.